# create database from with 2 distinct database according to customer name in python

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

**Table A: Product Attributes**

This table contains two columns; the first one is a unique product ID represented by an integer, the second is a string containing a collection of attributes assigned to that product.

```
product  tags
100      chocolate, sprinkles  
101      chocolate, sprinkles
102      glazed
```

**Table B: Customer Attributes**

The second table contains two columns as well; the first one is a string that contains a customer name, the second is an integer that contains a product number. The product IDs from column two are the same as the product IDs from column one of Table A.

```
customer  product
A        100
A        101
B        101
C        100
C        102
B        101
A        100
C        102
```

**Generated Table**

I want to create a table matching this format, where the contents of the cells represent the count of occurrences of product attribute by customer.

```
customer  chocolate sprinkles  glazed
A            ?          ?        ?
B            ?          ?        ?
C            ?          ?        ?
```

I want count instead of ?.
And I want to do this in python.

**One more question:**  If the two starting tables were in a relational database or Hadoop cluster and each had 100 million rows, how might my approach change?

Comment: Please mention what approaches you tried and the difficulty faced while trying that approach. Also what is the datatype of each item in the tag? Is it a list of strings or a tuple ?

Comment: I have done this using R but would like do this in python.

Comment: Please expand on how you solved this using R. all functionalities in R are also available in python. It would provide some one reading the question with a starting point for solving it in python.

Comment: Answer using R:
library(stringr)
library(reshape2)
library(dplyr)

#create the tables
tableA <- data.frame("product" = c(100, 101, 102),
                     "tags" = c("chocolate, sprinkles", "chocolate, sprinkles", "glazed"))

out <- strsplit(as.character(tableA$tags),', ') 
tags = do.call(rbind, out)
product=tableA$product

tableA=data.frame(product,tags)
tableA= melt(tableA, id=(c("product")))
tableA = tableA[,-2]
tableA

  product     value
1     100 chocolate
2     101 chocolate
3     102    glazed
4     100 sprinkles
5     101 sprinkles
6     102    glazed

Comment: after that  I also use below code to get final ans
tableB <- data.frame("customer" = c('A','A', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'B', 'A', 'C'),
                     "product" = c(100, 101, 101, 100, 102, 101, 100, 102))

a=merge(x = tableA, y = tableB, by = "product", all.x = TRUE)
a
a=a[,-1]


a1=a %>% 
  group_by(customer, value) %>% 
  summarise(n = n())

new=dcast(a1, customer ~ value , value.var="n", fill=0)
new

  customer chocolate glazed sprinkles
1        A         3      0         3
2        B         2      0         2
3        C         1      4         1